# possible to add list of selected value together in django?

Tags: python, django, calculation

for example I have this as my `list` in `django`

```
[
{'price': Decimal('45.00'), 'total': 1L, 'quantity': 1}
{'price': Decimal('45.00'), 'total': 1L, 'quantity': 1}
{'price': Decimal('45.00'), 'total': 2L, 'quantity': 1}
{'price': Decimal('40.00'), 'total': 1L, 'quantity': 1}
{'price': Decimal('40.00'), 'total': 1L, 'quantity': 1}
{'price': Decimal('49.00'), 'total': 1L, 'quantity': 1}
]
```

What I want my output to be is that the same price will be added togther but there's another catch which is, same price times the total.
For the example above, what I want as my output would be

```
[
{'price': Decimal('180.00'), 'total': 4L, 'quantity': 1}
{'price': Decimal('80.00'), 'total': 2L, 'quantity': 1}
{'price': Decimal('49.00'), 'total': 1L, 'quantity': 1}
]
```

since `price` `49` only has `total` of `1`, there is no changes to it.
As for price `40` it's total of two, so the output is `80` as for price of `45` it's total of `4` so `45*4=180`

I thought of the javascript `lodash` which this situtation came up and googled there is something called `pydash` but somehow I couldn't figure out the way to use it though.

Is anyone able to give me an idea how this can work with minimum loops?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the `L` or the `Decimal` notation, but here is something you could do to get the desired results:

```
from collections import defaultdict


lis = [
{'price': 45.00, 'total': '1L', 'quantity': 1},
{'price': 45.00, 'total': '1L', 'quantity': 1},
{'price': 45.00, 'total': '2L', 'quantity': 1},
{'price': 40.00, 'total': '1L', 'quantity': 1},
{'price': 40.00, 'total': '1L', 'quantity': 1},
{'price': 49.00, 'total': '1L', 'quantity': 1},
]

results = defaultdict(lambda: {'price':0, 'total':0, 'quantity':1})
for i in lis:
    results[i['price']]['price'] += i['price']*int(i['total'].strip('L'))
    results[i['price']]['total'] += int(i['total'].strip('L'))

print(list(results.values()))
```

This results in:

```
[{'price': 180.0, 'total': 4, 'quantity': 1}, 
{'price': 80.0, 'total': 2, 'quantity': 1}, 
{'price': 49.0, 'total': 1, 'quantity': 1}]
```